# BeautifulSoup find_all not working always

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am getting the page using selenium and phantomJS and using BeautifulSoup to scrap the data. This code sometimes works, most times doesn't. The URL I am using is of Google Flight.
I am unable to understand what might be causing it to fail so much.The driver returns the html content but no screenshot. Here is the code :

```
def update_ds():
print("Called")
url = "https://www.google.fr/flights#flt=DEL.r/m/02j9z.2018-11-10*r/m/02j9z.DEL.2018-11-14;c:USD;e:1;ls:1w;sd:0;t:e"
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='C:\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs')
dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = ("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36")
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='C:\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs',desired_capabilities=dcap,service_args = ['--ignore-ssl-errors=true'])
driver.implicitly_wait(120)
driver.get(url)
driver.save_screenshot('flight.png')
html_content = driver.page_source
#print(html_content)
print("Connected")

s = BeautifulSoup(html_content,"lxml")
best_price_tags = s.find_all('span',class_=['uKOpFp4SF2X__price flt-subhead2','uKOpFp4SF2X__price flt-subhead2 uKOpFp4SF2X__deal'])
print("tags ",len(best_price_tags))
best_price = []
for tag in best_price_tags:
    best_price.append(int(tag.string.replace('US$','').replace(',','')))
```

Comment: It looks like you're not waiting for the webapp to load contents - the `implicitly_wait` was before the `get(url)`. You'll need another wait because driver.get() does not wait for all `ajax` request to finish.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `By` and `WebDriverWait`. So you can wait until you found the class in your specific time.

> By https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html
>
> WebDriverWait https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

locator = (By.CLASS_NAME , 'uKOpFp4SF2X__price flt-subhead2')
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 120, 0.5).until(EC.element_to_be_selected(locator))
except:
    print("Could not find class")
```

Comment: It is printing could not find class always

Comment: @AkshraGupta increase time and change function, see what i changed

Comment: @AkshraGupta using different function to locator. Read link of `WebDriverWait`